# Why good local validation gives bad score on Kaggle Competition?

Tags: python, data-analysis, cross-validation, data-science, kaggle

This might be a general question.

I was trying to build a predictive model in a Kaggle competition. I used some of the traditional methods like Xgboost Lightgbm and Random Forest. I tried to split the train data to train and validation into 7:3.

```
X_train, X_vali, Y_train, Y_vali = cross_validation.train_test_split\
     (x_train, y_train, test_size=0.3, random_state=42);
```

Then build model and test if the parameters are the best.

```
model = Model.fit(x_train,y_train)
print(log_loss(y_true=Y_vali,y_pred=model.predict_proba(X_vali)))
```

Everything works well but I had a very bad score on the final submission. It seems like worse validation results even get a better score on Kaggle's kernel(Doesn't seems like an overfitting problem I guess). I don't know how to optimize my model because the Kaggle results seem unpredictable.

Does someone know why this problem happened?

Comment: Which dataset/competition are you working on? It would be great if we can reproduce your case.

Comment: Hi, @MuhammadNizami. It's KKBox's churn prediction. Competition ends now. Maybe you can download the dataset from the Kaggle page.